# Read and Write JSON in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

How to read and write JSON data in SQL Server  ?

Is it possible to add any type of index to JSON fields from SQL server ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server ?

Comment: @MarcGuillot If possible from 2012

Comment: You are out of luck, SQL Server didn't add support for JSON until SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server supports JSON from version 2016

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

JSON fields are indexed as normal text fields i belive